# select data in viewlist

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to ask a favor. I display the data in the access to the vb.net using viewlist, but if I want to select a name can not. Can you assist me? coding has been made but I do not know where the fault

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Public Class Guest_List
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dReader As OleDbDataReader
    Public title, FirstName, LastName, Address, Country, Company, DateIn, DateOut, RoomType, Note As String
    Private Sub Guest_List_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call list_data()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtKataKunci_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtKataKunci.TextChanged
        Call list_data()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Call pilih()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
        Call pilih()
    End Sub

    Private Sub list_data()

        Call clear_list()
        Dim sqlx As String
        Dim x As Integer

        sqlx = "select title,firstname,lastname,address,country,company,datein,dateout,roomtype,notes from tcekin where firstname like '%" & Trim(txtKataKunci.Text) & "%' order by firstname  asc"

        cnn = New OleDbConnection(strConn)
        If cnn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then cnn.Close()
        cnn.Open()
        cmmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlx, cnn)
        dReader = cmmd.ExecuteReader

        Try
            While dReader.Read = True
                x = Val(counter.Text)
                counter.Text = Str(Val(counter.Text) + 1)

                With ListView1
                    .Items.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("")
                    .Items(x).SubItems(0).Text = dReader.GetString(0)
                    .Items(x).SubItems(1).Text = dReader.GetString(1)
                    .Items(x).SubItems(2).Text = dReader.GetString(2)
                    .Items(x).SubItems(3).Text = dReader.GetString(3)
                    .Items(x).SubItems(4).Text = dReader.GetString(4)
                    .Items(x).SubItems(5).Text = dReader.GetString(5)
                    .Items(x).SubItems(6).Text = Format(CDate(dReader.GetDateTime(6)), "dd-MMMM-yyyy")
                    .Items(x).SubItems(7).Text = Format(CDate(dReader.GetDateTime(7)), "dd-MMMM-yyyy")
                    .Items(x).SubItems(8).Text = dReader.GetString(8)
                    .Items(x).SubItems(9).Text = dReader.GetString(9)
                End With
            End While
        Finally
            dReader.Close()
        End Try
        cnn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub clear_list()
        While Val(counter.Text) > 0
            ListView1.Items(0).Remove()
            counter.Text = Val(counter.Text) - 1
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub pilih()
        Try
            title = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text.ToString
            FirstName = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text.ToString
            LastName = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text.ToString
            Address = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text.ToString
            Country = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text.ToString
            Company = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text.ToString
            DateIn = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text.ToString
            DateOut = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(7).Text.ToString
            RoomType = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(8).Text.ToString
            Note = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(9).Text.ToString
            Me.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("pilih salah satu data", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "select a name"? Are you trying to query a specific name from the database?

Change your sqlx to

```
String.Format("select title,firstname,lastname,address,country,company,datein,dateout,roomtype,notes from tcekin where firstname like '%{0}%' order by firstname  asc", txtKataKunci.Text.Trim())
```

Then add a BreakPoint on the reader, hit F5 and see if any data is coming back from the db. You can also try running the query directly on the access db.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding your datareader to your listview using a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)

This way you will have all of the records returned by your sql statement.